# Calculate the difference between two unix timestamp date fields

Tags: views, datetime

I need to calculate the difference between two date fields in a table view in Views so that each row in the table shows the time difference in days, hours and minutes . The date fields are set to the Date Unix Timestamp. I've set it like that because I believe it's the best option for calculating 'seconds'. Once we know how many seconds there are between the two dates, we should be able to turn that into a human readable format of let's say days, hours, minutes. Can anyone tell me how this is accomplished?

Comment: You can try using https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php module....

Comment: One way is to override one of the templates outputting the second timestamp.  You would then run a calculation in PHP and output the time difference.

Comment: thanks. both suggestions require to write php code which is great but I don't know how to go about.